# IPhone and Cocos2d Sprites/Layers

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I am using cocos2d-iphone to place Sprites onto a Layer to setup a game playfield.  At certain points in the game, certain Sprites need to be removed based upon game conditions.  What I would like to do is setup an array of Sprite pointers, but I have two questions:

What's the best way to place Sprite pointers in an array?

How does one remove the Sprite in cocos2d with only a pointer to the Sprite?  I know how to do it from its parent layer, but that is too runtime intensive for the main game loop.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please feel free to accept your own answer instead of mine. By the sound of things, you were able to get it working using your method, and I won't be offended! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Sprite` class inherits from `CocosNode`, so you should be able to call `spritePointer.parent.remove(spritePointer)`

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out.  If anyone else is interested, the way to do it is to declare an array of Sprite pointers, such as:

```
Sprite * mySprites[10][10]; // assuming a 10x10 playfield where obstacles get placed
```

Then, when setting up your Sprites:

```
mySprites[0][0] = [Sprite spriteWithFile: @"obstacle.png"];   
[myLayer add:mySprites[0][0]];
```

To remove the Sprite:

```
[myLayer remove:mySprites[0][0]];
```

Answer (score 2):

There's also `[mySprite removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES]`.